# How to multiply odd index?

Tags: javascript, indexing

I have a little problem with my Javascript code. Here is my question :

I want to write a function, who take in input a table of numbers. If numbers situated in **even** index, *be returned as the way it is*. But, if numbers situated in **odd** index, *be return multiplied by his index*.

For example :

**Input :**

> [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 50, 100]

**Return :**

> [5, 10, 15, 60, 25, 150, 50, 700]

---

So, my code :

```
function multiplyNum(numbers) {
  const multiply = numbers.map(function(number) {
      for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
          return numbers
        }
        if (numbers[i] % 2 !== 0) {
          return numbers
        }
      });
    return multiplyNum
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see anywhere in your code where you're multiplying anything.  I only see you using the mod operator.  Am I just not seeing the multiplication?  Also, you're comparing your values in two different ways.  One way, you're doing a "double equals check" and the other, a "triple equals check".  

That is, you're doing an identity check in one and an equality check in another.  Take a look at this -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Note:  That's not gonna solve the problem here but consistency is good.

Comment: You have unbalanced braces. And you should return `multiply`, not `multiplyNum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `for` loop at all, you can get the index from the map and multiply the odd values:

```js
function multiplyNum(numbers) {
  return numbers.map(function(number, index) {
    return index % 2 ? number * index : number;
  });
}

console.log(multiplyNum([5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 50, 100]));
```

Comment: Actually, you're checking if the number is odd instead of the index.

Comment: Thanks for your Intervention @naeramarth7 , fixed now

Answer (score 2):

You could map with a conditional operator as a check.

```js
var array = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 50, 100],
    result = array.map((v, i) => i % 2 ? v * i : v);

console.log(result);
```